# How to selectively delete some of the properties from an existing JSON string?

Tags: c#, json

I have a nested JSON string.  I want to reduce the size of the JSON, selecting only some of the properties and omitting the rest.  How can I do it?

Sample JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 17,
        "Code": "1",
        "SupplierID": 24,
        "Date": "2018-07-04T10:16:37.107",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "ID": 17,
                "OrderID": 17,
                "ItemID": 5806,
                "Quantity": 20000.0,
                "ConfirmQuantity": 20000.0,
                "ConfirmDate": "2018-09-11T11:33:30.463",
                "Deadline": "2018-07-22T00:00:00",
                "IsCanceled": false,
                "PersonnelID": 667,
                "IsConfirmed": false
            },
            {
                "ID": 190,
                "OrderID": 170,
                "ItemID": 5806,
                "Quantity": 20000.0,
                "ConfirmQuantity": 20000.0,
                "ConfirmDate": "2018-09-11T11:33:30.463",
                "Deadline": "2018-07-22T00:00:00",
                "IsCanceled": false,
                "PersonnelID": 6670,
                "IsConfirmed": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 19,
        "Code": "2",
        "SupplierID": 20,
        "Date": "2018-07-14T13:25:50.030",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "ID": 18,
                "OrderID": 19,
                "ItemID": 15425,
                "Quantity": 2100.0,
                "ConfirmQuantity": 2100.0,
                "Deadline": "2018-07-18T00:00:00",
                "IsCanceled": false,
                "PersonnelID": 445,
                "IsConfirmed": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 17,
        "Code": "1",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "ID": 17,
                "ItemID": 5806,
                "Quantity": 20000.0,
            },
            {
                "ID": 190,
                "ItemID": 5806,
                "Quantity": 20000.0,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 19,
        "Code": "2",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "ID": 18,
                "ItemID": 15425,
                "Quantity": 2100.0,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You look at the documentation for LINQ and JSON.NET

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried implementing this yourself? If so please add the code here and ask about a problem with the implementation. If not, you should first try to do it yourself and after that if you have a problem, ask a more specific question. Please read [ask]

Comment: If you want to parse your `JSON` string dynamically, you can see demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JSwxY6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API to do something like this:

```
var namesToKeep = new string[] { "ID", "Code", "OrderDetails", "ItemID", "Quantity" };
var jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var prop in jArray.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().ToList())
{
    if (!namesToKeep.Contains(prop.Name))
        prop.Remove();
}
jsonString = jArray.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pj9Wsu

Answer (score 0):

In order to exclude properties from serialization, you need to mark properties with `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

Something like this:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double ConfirmQuantity { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime ConfirmDate { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsCanceled { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int PersonnelID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

But I actually advice you to project your original collection into collection of objects which have subset of properties.

The easiest is to define new class with only properties which you want to serialize, and map from one to another (using plain LINQ `Select`, or somekind of a mapper):

```
public class OrderDetailModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetailModel> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```